# React: Close hamburger menu when clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the following scenario

Currently when a user clicks on the hamburger menu, then the user is navigated to the specific page, but when a user is on the home page and clicks on the home link from the menu, then the hamburger menu stays open. I want to dismiss/hide/close the menu even if the user is on the same page as they are clicking on the same link. For example: if the user is on home page and clicks on the home link from the menu, the menu should close. How can I achieve this

```
onLinkClick(){
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.name, this.props.link);
}

onItemClick: () =>{

};

<SomeDiv onClick = {this.onLinkClick} link={this.props.link}>
    {this.props.name}
</SomeDiv >
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options depending on your architecture:

1. Pass down a function which toggles the drawer to the page and close it in `onLinkClick`
2. [using Redux]: Keep the hamburger state (opened / closed) in a reducer and from `onLinkClick` dispatch an action creator to close it

Comment: can you give an example